# PHP - How to set footer in SoapClient

Tags: php, footer, soap-client

With PHP, I need to send a SOAP request with a parameter (Hash) in the footer. I'm using SoapClient but I can not figure out how to do this, neither in internet searches, nor in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php).

This is the envelope I used in the SoapUI tool to test:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:abc="" xmlns:abc1="" xmlns:abc2="">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <abc:Method>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <abc:request>
            <abc1:Header>
               <abc1:Username>Username</abc1:Username>
               <abc1:Password>Password</abc1:Password>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <abc1:PublicKeyUid></abc1:PublicKeyUid>
            </abc1:Header>
            <abc1:Body>
               <abc2:Id></abc2:Id>
            </abc1:Body>
            <abc1:Footer>
                <abc1:Hash></abc1:Hash>
            </abc1:Footer>
         </abc:request>
      </abc:Method>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

There is [The SoapHeader class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapheader.php) e the [SoapClient::__setSoapHeaders](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php) method but I find nothing related to the footer.

I do not have access to the server and should follow this structure mentioned above.

What I need to know is how to send the HASH parameter that is inside the footer with SoapClient.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion.

Comment: The correct usage of SOAP (assuming the SOAP server is correctly written) does not involve using XML.

Comment: What you basically need to do is to create an instance of `SoapClient` and pass the WSDL to its constructor then call its methods `__getFunctions()` and `__getTypes()` and inspect what they return. The describe the methods of the remote SOAP server you can invoke using the SOAP client you just created. There is no need to XML. You call the listed methods using regular method calls on the SOAPClient object.

Comment: @axiac. Thanks for the comment! I know it does not involve using XML, I wrote the XML envelope to show how the sending is expected. I copied the envelop I used in the SoapUI tool to test the WSDL.

Comment: The `SoapHeader` class deals with the SOAP headers present in the envelope (`<soapenv:Header/>`). It is not related in any way with the `<abc1:Header>` element present in the payload body.

Comment: The "Footer" you've shown is inside the body of the SOAP request, and inside the method definition. As far as the SOAP client is concerned, your method takes a single argument, `<request>`, which is either an XML document, or a structure with three sub-structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [IMSoP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157957/imsop) and [axiac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265352/axiac) have commented, the footer (`<abc1: Footer>`) is just a sub-structure of the envelop body and not a standard XML envelop element. I had not realized this and so I did not find it in the documentation.

So to send HASH to the requested structure, I need to pass a multidimensional array on the body element. The code looks like this:

```
$arrParameters = [
    'request'=>[
        'Header'=>[
            'Username'=>$strUsername,
            'Password'=>$strPassword
        ],
        'Body'=>[
            ...
        ],
        'Footer'=>[
            'Hash'=>$strHash
        ]
    ]
];

$SoapClient = new SoapClient(<WSDL URL>);

$resp = $SoapClient->method($arrParameters);
```

Thank you [IMSoP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157957/imsop) and [axiac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265352/axiac)!